# Get ComboBox text content and pass to a TextBox

Tags: wpf, combobox, vb.net-2010

Looking for a way to get a selected string value from among 100+ values populated in a ComboBox.
Below function designed to get intended values from the DB and return values back to ComboBox.

```
Public Function popuList(Optional dt As DataTable = Nothing)
    Dim daParties As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT party_ID, party_Name FROM tbl_Parties ORDER BY party_Name;", connKMVTDB)
    Dim dsParties As New DataSet
    Dim dtParties As New DataTable

    daParties.Fill(dsParties, "party_Name")
    dtParties = dsParties.Tables(0)

    Return dtParties
End Function
```

As expected the below event also works fine.

```
Private Sub btnPartyLOV_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnPartyLOV.Click
    If cmbPartiesList.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible Then
        cmbPartiesList.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    Else
        Dim dtParties As DataTable
        dtParties = popuList()

        cmbPartiesList.ItemsSource = dtParties.DefaultView
        cmbPartiesList.DisplayMemberPath = dtParties.Columns(1).ToString
        cmbPartiesList.SelectedValuePath = dtParties.Columns(0).ToString

        cmbPartiesList.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
        'cmbPartiesList.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

But how to get the selected text value from the ComboBox onto another TextBox? Tried below and stuck...

```
Private Sub cmbPartiesList_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles cmbPartiesList.SelectionChanged
    Dim selItem As String = DirectCast(cmbPartiesList.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString()

    MsgBox(selItem)
    lblID.Content = cmbPartiesList.SelectedValue
    txtAdd1.Text = cmbPartiesList.DisplayMemberPath
    cmbPartiesList.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
End Sub
```

I repeatedly get the error...

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'

Here stranded for a long time and any help will be highly appreciated & praised.

Comment: I think you cant cast cmbPartiesList.SelectedItem to ComboBoxItem

Answer (score 0):

Remember...  `ToString()`  is your friend!

Its as simple as this:

```
Private Sub cmbPartiesList_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles cmbPartiesList.SelectionChanged
    Dim selItem As String = cmbPartiesList.SelectedItem.ToString()
    MsgBox(selItem)

    lblID.Content = cmbPartiesList.SelectedValue
    txtAdd1.Text = cmbPartiesList.DisplayMemberPath
    cmbPartiesList.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that Matthew, with no use. Look...

```
Private Sub cmbPartiesList_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles cmbPartiesList.SelectionChanged
    Dim drv As DataRowView = cmbPartiesList.SelectedItem
    txtPName.Text = drv.Item(1).ToString()
End Sub
```

This solved my problem, error, doubt, etc.
Here I created a DataRowView class to store the current row items being passed during this call. The result is collected as a row and splitting them with item object, which essentially exposes the underlying results.

Anyhow, thanks for your time.
Any suggestions/corrections/modifications/improvements/criticisms on the above is highly appreciated.